# Issue with maven resolving a jar/dependency installed to local maven repository

Tags: maven

I installed a jar file locally via

```
mvn install:install-file  
    -Dfile=/usr/home/myname/Downloads/com/google/appengine/appengine-mapper/1.0/appengine-mapper-1.0.jar \
       -DgroupId=com.google.appengine \
       -DartifactId=appengine-mapper \
       -Dversion=1.0 \
       -Dpackaging=jar \
```

which was successful.

When trying to maven compile, I get the following error.

Could not resolve dependencies for project myproject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.google.appengine:appengine-mapper:jar:1.0 in http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of google-api-services has elapsed or updates are forced.

My pom.xml file:
...

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>google-api-services</id>
    <url>http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->    
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-mapper</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

...

What am I doing wrong. Maven is still trying to pull in the dependency from the remote repository.

Comment: Just try to delete the directory and retry building.

Comment: Even if you remove the remote repository?

Comment: Deleting the directory and trying to rebuild did it...Thanks.